# Increase the size for mobile menu by dragging

Tags: html, css, mobile, blueprint-css

I have a mobile menu for which I would like to increase the size of the menu by dragging it. Currently what I am doing is fixing it to a size of 50% of the screen. Below is how the menu looks.

[image]

The CSS, which I used to drag, doesn't work in this case.

```
.cbp-spmenu-bottom.cbp-spmenu-open {
    bottom: 8%;
    width: 100%;
  /*   height: 55%; */
    background: black;
    opacity: 1;
      overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    resize: vertical;
}
```

What could I do, so that I could touch the top bar, and resize the menu?

Comment: Can you make more information or give all code.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you dont set the position of the css to be fixed otherwise,you wont be able to drag.

```
position:fixed
```

Or you can set the position of the but what you can do is set it fixed after you resize and drag it as shown in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404907/how-to-use-jquery-draggable-with-fixed-position)

> **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dX8N3/24/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/draggab) is a website which might help you. If this is unable to help you, you could check [this](http://www.w3schools.com) website which has information on everything you can ever know about coding.

**EDIT:** 
You could try this sample code- `<button onclick="myFunction(width:200%;height:200%)">Increase Size Of Menu</button>`

I hope I helped you enough so you can be able to do what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the resize property is that it is not supported by most mobile browsers. You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) and [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize).

If you want mobile support a javascript solution would be your only choice.
You can try a library like [interact.js](http://interactjs.io/) which seems to work fine on mobile devices.